# snap packages on Debian stable

Tags: debian, snapcraft

Snaps are marketed as "universal Linux package" that can be installed anywhere...

I seem to be encountering problems with snapd on Debian stable (stretch). Such as taking 3 minutes to remove a package:

```
2017-09-09T15:08:29+10:00 ERROR cannot remove snap file "robotica", will retry in 3 mins: snap-robotica-x1.mount failed to stop: timeout
```

I also appear to be having random problems with snaps getting installed with the wrong permissions:

```
$ ls -l /snap/robotica                                  
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   2 Sep  9 14:32 current -> x7
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 139 Sep  9 14:03 x5
drwx------ 9 root root 153 Sep  9 14:30 x6
drwx------ 9 root root 153 Sep  9 14:30 x7
```

I understand that snapd in Debian is old, however I tried back-porting snapd in unstable to stretch, but it fails with the following errors:

```
...
# github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap-seccomp
src/github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap-seccomp/main.go:400: undefined: seccomp.ArchPPC
src/github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap-seccomp/main.go:402: undefined: seccomp.ArchPPC64
src/github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap-seccomp/main.go:404: undefined: seccomp.ArchPPC64LE
src/github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap-seccomp/main.go:406: undefined: seccomp.ArchS390X
src/github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap-seccomp/main.go:422: undefined: seccomp.ArchPPC64
src/github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap-seccomp/main.go:424: undefined: seccomp.ArchPPC64LE
src/github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap-seccomp/main.go:426: undefined: seccomp.ArchPPC
src/github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap-seccomp/main.go:428: undefined: seccomp.ArchS390X
src/github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap-seccomp/main.go:571: undefined: seccomp.ArchPPC
...
dh_auto_build: go install -v -p 1 -buildmode=pie -pkgdir=/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>/_build/std github.com/snapcore/snapd/arch github.com/snapcore/snapd/asserts github.com/snapcore/snapd/asserts/assertstest github.com/snapcore/snapd/asserts/signtool github.com/snapcore/snapd/asserts/snapasserts github.com/snapcore/snapd/asserts/sysdb github.com/snapcore/snapd/asserts/systestkeys github.com/snapcore/snapd/boot github.com/snapcore/snapd/boot/boottest github.com/snapcore/snapd/client github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap-exec github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap-repair github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap-seccomp github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap-update-ns github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snapctl github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snapd github.com/snapcore/snapd/daemon github.com/snapcore/snapd/dirs github.com/snapcore/snapd/errtracker github.com/snapcore/snapd/httputil github.com/snapcore/snapd/i18n github.com/snapcore/snapd/i18n/dumb github.com/snapcore/snapd/i18n/xgettext-go github.com/snapcore/snapd/image github.com/snapcore/snapd/interfaces github.com/snapcore/snapd/interfaces/apparmor github.com/snapcore/snapd/interfaces/backends github.com/snapcore/snapd/interfaces/builtin github.com/snapcore/snapd/interfaces/dbus github.com/snapcore/snapd/interfaces/ifacetest github.com/snapcore/snapd/interfaces/kmod github.com/snapcore/snapd/interfaces/mount github.com/snapcore/snapd/interfaces/policy github.com/snapcore/snapd/interfaces/seccomp github.com/snapcore/snapd/interfaces/systemd github.com/snapcore/snapd/interfaces/udev github.com/snapcore/snapd/logger github.com/snapcore/snapd/osutil github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/assertstate github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/auth github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/cmdstate github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate/config github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/devicestate github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/hookstate github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/hookstate/ctlcmd github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/hookstate/hooktest github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/ifacestate github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/patch github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/snapstate github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/snapstate/backend github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/state github.com/snapcore/snapd/partition github.com/snapcore/snapd/partition/androidbootenv github.com/snapcore/snapd/partition/grubenv github.com/snapcore/snapd/partition/ubootenv github.com/snapcore/snapd/progress github.com/snapcore/snapd/release github.com/snapcore/snapd/snap github.com/snapcore/snapd/snap/snapdir github.com/snapcore/snapd/snap/snapenv github.com/snapcore/snapd/snap/snaptest github.com/snapcore/snapd/snap/squashfs github.com/snapcore/snapd/store github.com/snapcore/snapd/strutil github.com/snapcore/snapd/systemd github.com/snapcore/snapd/testutil github.com/snapcore/snapd/timeout github.com/snapcore/snapd/timeutil github.com/snapcore/snapd/wrappers github.com/snapcore/snapd/x11 returned exit code 2
debian/rules:104: recipe for target 'override_dh_auto_build' failed
```

So is is sensible trying to get this to work? Or just I just cut my loses and give up now? Maybe snapcraft is only really useful on Ubuntu.

Comment: The error is quite clear. Run the `go install -v -p 1 ...` command manually and see what it gives you

Comment: The command doesn't appear to produce any output that says why it failed apart from the exit code of 2.

Comment: Oh wait, I see the errors now. Have amended the question.

Comment: Looks like some dependencies for `snap-seccomp` are missing. Did you install the build dependencies?

Comment: Yes, of course I did. However I now suspect that golang-github-seccomp-libseccomp-golang in Debian stable is also too old, so I have backported that and now retrying.

Comment: Ok, finally got newest version installed, but looks like it doesn't help the problem of removing snaps :-( - exactly the same error still.

Comment: The problem with permissions - which I still get - might be this https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapcraft/+bug/1515394 - although very odd it sometimes worked.

Comment: Why do you want to port snap to Debian?

Comment: I don't want to port snap to Debian. I want to get snap working on Debian/stable. Debian is my preferred platform, and snap packages are suppose to be installable anywhere.

Comment: Well, the concept of snap is quite different from dpkg / deb. Why do you want to install packages via snap? I'm just curious

Comment: So I can have a self contained package that includes all required Python dependencies of known versions that auto-updates. I mean all the reasons snap was created in the first place.

Comment: Imo you should be able to find 99% of the software you need in the Debian repositories. For that 1% of other software there are better ways to deploy it than the snap approach. For Python, virtualenv should do what you want. But I know that is an ongoing discussion. I personally don't like the concept of snap (and competitors).